# Can't use range on slice made with reflect then passed json.Unmarshal

Tags: reflection, go, type-conversion, slice

I am getting the following errors from the code below:

> invalid indirect of typedSlice (type interface {})
>
> cannot range over typedSlice (type interface {})

This is confusing to me because `reflect.TypeOf(copy)` matches the type of `t`.

```
func Unmarshal(t reflect.Type) []interface{} {

    ret := []interface{}{}
    s := `[{"Name":"The quick..."}]`

    slice := reflect.Zero(reflect.SliceOf(t))
    o := reflect.New(slice.Type())
    o.Elem().Set(slice)
    typedSlice := o.Interface()

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), typedSlice)

    fmt.Println(typedSlice)                 // &[{The quick...}]
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(typedSlice)) //same type as t
    fmt.Println(*typedSlice)                // invalid indirect of copy (type interface {})

    for _, l := range typedSlice {          //cannot range over copy (type interface {})
        ret = append(ret, &l)
    }

    return ret
}
```

I've created a [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VNKnuzRaiH) with working code to help.

Why does it appear that this slice prints one type but compiles as another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> invalid indirect of typedSlice (type interface {})

You can't dereference `typedSlice`, because it's an `interface{}`. You would have to extract the pointer with a type assertion

```
realSlice := *typedSlice.(*[]Demo)
```

> cannot range over typedSlice (type interface {})

Again, since `typedSlice` is an `interface{}`, you can't range over it. If you want to range over the values you need to use a type assertion, or iterate manually via reflect:

```
for i := 0; i < o.Elem().Len(); i++ {
    ret = append(ret, o.Elem().Index(i).Interface())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, however I can't get them to work.  I would need to be able to do the type assertion with the reflect type...so .(*[]Demo) would not work.  Also, o.Elem() returns the error `(type interface {} is interface with no methods)`.  Not sure what to do with that...

Comment: @RickSmith: No, you can't use a type assertion with reflection. Cut&pasted into your code: https://play.golang.org/p/aTv4y4Ye9C (added a call to Interface() which is probably more like what you intended)

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you renamed `typedSlice` to `o`...but you didn't.  Sometimes I make unfounded and crazy assumptions that make things not work :(  I think this has answered my question; thank you for your answer and your patience.