# How to range over slice of a custom type

Tags: go

I'm trying to write in Go custom cache for Google DataStore (more precisely - a wrapper around one of existing cache libraries). At cache initialisation, it should accept any **custom type of struct** (with appropriately-defined datastore fields), which then would be the basis for all items stored. The idea is that cache can be created/initialised for various types which reflect the structure of a particular DataStore entry (*CustomEntry*)

**Approach 1** - store *reflect.Type* and use it. **Problem encountered** - can't iterate over a slice of a custom type

```
type CustomEntry struct {
    Data struct {
        name          string   `datastore:"name,noindex"`
        address       []string `datastore:"address,noindex"`
    } `datastore:"data,noindex"`
}

func (cache *MyCache) CacheData(dataQuery string, dataType reflect.Type) {
    slice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(dataType), 10, 10)

    if keys, err := DataStoreClient.GetAll(cache.ctx, datastore.NewQuery(dataQuery), &slice); err != nil {
        //handle error
    } else {
        for i, dataEntry:= range slice {
        // ERROR: Cannot range over 'slice' (type Value)
            cache.Set(keys[i].Name, dataEntry)
        }
}

//usage: Cache.CacheData("Person", reflect.TypeOf(CustomEntry{})
```

**Approach 2** - accept an array of interfaces as arguments. **Problem encountered** = *[]CustomEntry* is not *[]interface{}*

```
func (cache *MyCache) CacheData(dataQuery string, dataType []interface{}) {
    if keys, err := DataStoreClient.GetAll(cache.ctx, datastore.NewQuery(dataQuery), &dataType); err != nil {
        //handle error
    } else {
        for i, dataEntry:= range slice {
        // this seems to work fine
            cache.Set(keys[i].Name, dataEntry)
        }
}

//usage: 
var dataType []CustomEntry
Cache.CacheData("Person", data)
// ERROR: Cannot use 'data' (type []CustomEntry) as type []interface{}
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked for Qs like https://stackoverflow.com/a/34163477/4466350 ?

Comment: Yes, I have searched wide and deep. The usual solution is to simply type-assert before iterating, but - as I understand - this cannot be done with reflection (when you don't know in advance what type you are actually asserting). That's why I thought that providing more context about my use case might lead some of the more experienced people to some potential workarounds.

Comment: There are no dynamic types in Go.

Comment: @Zack cache or no cache, do not use unexported fields if you expect them to be accessed by a package other then the one in which they were declared. `reflect.MakeSlice` returns a value of type `reflect.Value` therefore passing `&slice` to `GetAll` is *wrong* and attempting to `range` over `slice` is also *wrong*. Look into the `reflect` package's documentation to figure out how to get `*[]<CustomType>` (which is what you need to pass to `GetAll`) from `slice` and how to iterate over the elements of *any* slice contained by a `reflect.Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution and thought it might be worth sharing in case anyone else has a similar problem.

The easiest way is to initiate a slice of structs which the DataStore is expected to receive, and then to pass a pointer to it as an argument (interface{}) into the desired function. DataStore, similarly to a few unmarshaling functions (I have tried with JSON package) will be able to successfully append the data to it.

Trying to dynamically create the slice within the function, given a certain Type, which would be then accepted by a function (such as DataStore client) might be quite difficult (I have not managed to find a way to do it). Similarly, passing a slice of interfaces (to allow for easy iteration) only complicates things.

Secondly, in order to iterate over the data (e.g. to store it in cache), it is necessary to: 
(1) retrieve the underlying value of the interface (i.e. the pointer itself) - this can be achieved using `reflect.ValueOf(pointerInterface)`, 
(2) dereference the pointer so that we obtain access to the underlying, iterable slice of structs - this can be done by invoking `.Elem()`,
(3) iterate over the underlying slice using `.Index(i)` method (`range` will not accept an interface, even if the underlying type is iterable).

Naturally, adding a number of switch-case statements might be appropriate to ensure that any errors are caught rather than cause a runtime panic.

Hence the following code provides a working solution to the above problem:

In main:

```
var data []customEntry
c.CacheData("Person",&data)
```

And the function itself:

```
func (cache *MyCache) CacheData(dataQuery string, data interface{}) error {
    if keys, err := DataStoreClient.GetAll(cache.ctx, datastore.NewQuery(dataQuery), data); err != nil {
        return err
    } else {
        s := reflect.ValueOf(data).Elem()
        for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
            cache.Set(keys[i].Name, s.Index(i), 1)
        }
    }
}
```